# Title of Barbutton item in toolbar visible on IOS 6 but not on IOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitoolbar

I am using the below code for toolbar & it is showing title for IOS 6 but not fro IOS 7.

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"multimedia/icon_settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain                                                                  target:self                                                                 action:@selector(pressSettings:)];
UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"multimedia/icon_refresh.png"]                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self                                                                 action:@selector(pressRefresh:)];
UIBarButtonItem *helpButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"multimedia/icon_help.png"]                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pressHelp:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

/* Set the title of the button */
[settingButton setTitle:@"Settings"];
[refreshButton setTitle:@"Refresh"];
[helpButton setTitle:@"Help"];
[feedbackButton setTitle:@"Feedback"];

NSArray *toolbarButtons = @[settingButton, flexSpace, helpButton, flexSpace, feedbackButton, flexSpace, refreshButton];

[self setToolbarItems:toolbarButtons];
```

This code working fine with IOS 6 but shows only bar button image in IOS 7 not title.

Comment: In which method you've put this code in your viewcontroller?

Comment: I have put it on viewdidload... it's working perfect on IOS 6 but on IOS 7, it shows only image not title..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UINavigationController maintains a UIToolBar for each view controller in its stack. This toolbar is normally hidden. So, you need to explicitly show the toolbar:

```
[self.navController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

Get the navigation controller of your viewcontroller and set the above setToolbarHidden property to NO.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Toolbar is visible & working fine with IOS 7.But when I use the above code, it just shows image on toolbar button item, not its title with IOS 7.

Comment: Apple has made changes for almost every UI elements on transition from ios 6 to ios 7.I could explain more clearly if you add the snapshot image of your toolbar before you made a fix.

Comment: You can also have a look at this :: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH8-SW6

Comment: @Bikram.. can you please give your email ID , I will email you the screenshot as I didn't find any way to upload screenshot on stack..I have used the toolbar as bottom bar & added bar button items. I set the image & title on this bottom toolbar. Now when I run app on IOS 6, I got to see all bar button items of toolbar with bar button items image & title but in case of IOS 7, I got only image of bar button items, its title is not displaying.